# How to php echo an image with set size

Tags: php, html, syntax

I am echoing an image which works fine, but then i want to set how big it needs to be, and I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

This is what I have:

```
echo "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "' height="130" width="150"> ";
```

What am I doing wrong? If I remove the height and width it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing single and double quotes. So you get a syntax error.

This works:

```
echo "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "' height='130' width='150'> ";
```

If you like to output double quotes you have to escape:

```
echo "<img src=\"" . $row['imglink'] . "\" height=\"130\" width=\"150\"> ";
```

Or you switch to cover the string in single quotes:

```
echo '<img src="' . $row['imglink'] . '" height="130" width="150"> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

ok its here

```
echo '<img src="'$row['imglink']'" height="130" width="150">';
```

Comment: This does set the image size but does not display the image itself.

Comment: ok. pls paste source code. because every thing is ok for this code

Comment: figured it out-> echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink'].' " height="130" width="150">';

Comment: try it without points?

Answer (score 1):

try changing double quotes into single quotes for these attributes

```
height='130' width='150'
```

since double quotes are actually delimiting the PHP string. Optionally you may instead escape the double quotes like so

```
height=\"130\" width=\"150\"
```

but this syntax is less readable and more error prone (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You can uses variables inside double quotes, like this:

```
<?
    $img_url = $row['imglink'];
    echo "<img src='$img_url' height='130' width='150'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the way that you're using causes to errors if you don't do it properly.Therefore you can try this way also.

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['imglink']?>" height="130" width="150" />
```

if you're using this inside a loop,you can do like this.

```
<?php foreach($result as $rows):?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['imglink']?>" height="130" width="150" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this helped to you.